# JavaScript/jQuery: replace part of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

With text like this:

```
<div class="element">
<span>N/A, Category</span>
</div>
```

I want to get rid of every occurrence of `N/A`.

Here is my attempt:

```
$('.element span').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        $(this).text().replace('N/A, ', '');
    });
```

The logged text is the text inside of the span so the selector is okay.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `replace` **returns** a string, it does not perform in place changes. And even then, the text would be set to the element automatically.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to set the text after the replace call:

```js
$('.element span').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  var text = $(this).text().replace('N/A, ', '');
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <span>N/A, Category</span>
</div>
```

---

Here's another cool way you can do it (hat tip @Felix King):

```
$(".element span").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace("N/A, ", "");
});
```

Comment: Or pass a function: `$(this).text(function(i, text) { return text.replace(...);});`

Comment: @Felix: Good call, I always forget about that version.

Comment: +1 for the second version, upvote one of @Felix 's answers to transfer it to him :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Haha, yep. I've given @Felix plenty of upvotes already :)

Comment: @Andrew I guess most of us have :).

Answer (score 14):

It should be like this

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace('N/A, ', ''))
```