# Jquery replace for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, each

I want to replace every "New" inside every link with span tag.

Is it right?

```
$("a:contains('New')").each(function () {
                 $(this).html($(this).html().replace("New", "<span class='new'>New</span>"));
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple method as well:

```
$("a:contains('New')").each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace('New', '<span class="new">New</span>');
    });
});
```

From here: [JavaScript/jQuery: replace part of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177200/javascript-jquery-replace-part-of-string)

Edit:

[Ricardo Lohmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336366/1339786)'s answer is better, kills the each() function:

```
$("a:contains('New')").html(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/New/g, '<span class="new">New</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Regex : **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/WujTJ/

g = /g modifier makes sure that all occurrences of "replacement"

i - /i makes the regex match case insensitive.

**A good read:** if you keen: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Please try this:

Hope this help `:)`

Also note you might not need to check if it contains `New` or not, because regex will change if need be:

```
   // $("a:contains('New')").each(function () { // NOT sure if you need this
                     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/New/g, "<span class='new'>New</span>"));
      //      });
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried your code ?
It's working well as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/zZyLp/1/), the only problem is that you forgot to use `g` modifier to replace all `"New"` ocurrences.

Other problem is that you don't need each loop, as you can see the following code do the same thing.
The difference is that **it's not necessary to loop and get item html twice**.

```
$("a:contains('New')").html(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/New/g, '<span class="new">New</span>');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/zZyLp/3/)